# Plot different colored lines with multiple colored sections

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have a line plot where I have 2 lines with 2 different color and each line would have sections colored in different shades of that color. Like a gradient shade for each line. e.g. a line with shades of blue for different regions along the x-axis

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(a = c(rep(0,10), rep(1,10)),
                 b = c(rep(c(rep(0,3),rep(1,4),rep(2,3)), 2)),
                 c = sample(1:20),
                 d = c(1:20))
df

ggplot(data = df) + geom_line(aes(x = d, y = c, color = factor(a),
linetype = factor(b)))
```

[image]
Here I get each line with different color. Tried adding a different linetype to each section but that doesn't work. Each line should by itself have different shades based on column `b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using alpha and line size instead of linetype.

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + 
    geom_line(aes(d, c, 
                  color = factor(a), group = a,
                  size = factor(b), alpha = factor(b))) +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0.6, 0.2)) +
    scale_size_manual(values = c(2, 1, 0.5))
```

Result:

[image]

---

Data (`df`):

```
structure(list(a = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), b = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), c = c(6L, 13L, 10L, 20L, 2L, 11L, 15L, 
5L, 3L, 7L, 17L, 4L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 19L, 9L, 8L, 18L, 16L), d = 1:20), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: good solution buddy ! I still would have first preference for different shades as the number of levels here is 5. Hence thicker lines makes plot too dense

Comment: @joel.wilson doesn't alpha give your different shades?

Comment: it does. But very very light. Can we tweak it to get  little darker shades?

Comment: Make the colors darker to then give darker shades

Comment: thanks bro ! I played around with this and it worked!!

Comment: @joel.wilson happy to help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

create a ramp from blue to red of 8 colors used first 3 colors to map the blues and last three to map the reds. Color based on interaction of a and b:

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))

ggplot(data = df)+
  geom_line(aes(x = d, y = c, color = interaction(b, a), group = a)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colfunc(8)[c(1:3,6:8)])
```

[image]

or something along these lines:

```
bfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("blue3", "dodgerblue", "firebrick1", "darkred"))

ggplot(data = df)+
  geom_line(aes(x = d, y = c, color = interaction(b, a), group = a)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = bfunc(6))
```

[image]